# Missing productTypeIdentifier error using new Apple Build System (xcbuild)

Tags: xcode

I have an XCode project that builds with the legacy build system, but when using the new build system under xcode11 immediately fails with the err:

```
.. forcing incremental PIF cache clear after loading error: Required key 'productTypeIdentifier' is missing in StandardTarget dictionary
note: Using new build system
error: Build service could not start build operation: unknown error while handling message: MsgHandlingError(message: "no PIF transfer has been initiated")
```

I'm looking for any info that might help clarify this.
What is a 'StandardTarget dictionary'? Can I add the missing key directly? Or is this a consequence some other setting?
Are there any 'PIF transfer' experts out there?